# Delete multiple strings in an array

Tags: php, arrays, magento, controller, array-difference

I have a array value saved in the database as below;

```
$databasearray = a_name.pdf,b_name.pdf,c_name.zip
```

and in my controller I am trying to update the database with the values the user selects;

**[EDIT]{My code has the variables wrapped in and array()**

```
 //my Database Value
 //load data for current item
 $model = Mage::getModel('things/things')->load($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
 $array1 = array($model->getDatabaseValue());//a_name.pdf,b_name.pdf,c_name.zip

//my selected values from admin form fieldset (checkbox[])(from database array value)
$array2 = array($this->getRequest()->getParam('to_delete'));//a_name.pdf,b_name.pdf

$results = array_diff($array1, $array2);

//save new array value with selected values removed
$savemodel->saveDatabaseValue(implode(',', $results));
```

Problem is that the new values are that is being saved are they same as the original value and it as if the array_diff() is not working how ever a dump of the $array1 & $array2 I can see that they are different values.

```
implode(',', $results)); outputs all values and does not remove $array2 values even though $array2 has values from $array1
```

any reason why the values are not being pasted/removed from the array_diff? Iam I suppose to explode/implode somewhere else in the event?

Comment: Having `var_dump($array1)` and `var_dump($array2)` results attached to your question could significantly help to understand your problem.

Comment: cant test your suggestion yet but $array1 & $array2 are both just thing1,thing2,thing3 & thing2,thing3 strings